# Embed Google Photo image in spreadsheet

Tags: image, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Is it possible to embed in Spreadsheets an image from a Google Photo (Google+ in GDrive) folder?

I have images in Google+ albums and with new functionality show them in Google Drive in location: `My Drive/Google Photo ...`. I tried to show these images in Spreadsheets with:

```
=image("https://googledrive.com/host/FOLDERID/NAMEPHOTO.jpg")
```

but see nothing, no image, no errors just a blank cell.

What should I do?

In the major I want to organize (moving, upload etc.) and edit (rename) images in album on Google+ with function and google scripts for spreadsheet. So I try use new functionality - Google Photo Albums see in GDrive - to do this. **And finally i need to show the images from albums Google+ (folder Google Photo in GDrive) in Spreadsheet Cells.**

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried, but it not resole issue.

Answer (score 3):

Google Drive hosting (googledrive.com/host/FOLDERID/...) is being [deprecated](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.tw/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html). To properly embed an image on Google Drive, you need to follow the following steps:

1. In Google Drive, right click on an image and select either "Share..." or "Get Link"
2. You will get a link that looks either like:

   - drive.google.com/file/d/RaD0mNum3er/view?usp=sharing , or
   - drive.google.com/open?id=RaD0mNum3er
3. You need to convert the link to something like:

   - drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=RaD0mNum3er
4. In your cell, enter =image("drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=RaD0mNum3er")

To quicken the process, I'd create 3 new columns (let's say C, D, E).

- C2 = drive.google.com/open?id=RaD0mNum3er
- D2 = =REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"(?:(?:file/d/)|(?:open\?id=))(\w+)")
- E2 = ="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="&E2

where

- C is the link you got from Google Drive
- D is the extracted file ID, and
- E is the converted the permalink

Comment: Correction, E2 should be have "D2" at the end instead of "E2"

Comment: Problem is when you need use fineName rather then fileID. Do you know solution ?